# Pandas Groupby : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've tried another solution with this error on SO they all are related to Python input or raw_input and didn't solve my problem.

```
txt = '''series NAME VAL1 VAL2 
0 AAA 27 678 
1 BBB 45 744
2 CCC 34 275
3 AAA 29 932
4 CCC 47 288
5 BBB 24 971
'''
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt),sep = '\s+')
del df['series']
df = df.groupby('NAME').apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

> > TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

But if I check individually (max, min) they work. I've checked the type of columns `VAL1` and `VAL2`and they are of `int64` type

Comment: Also, if you're trying to answer the other question, I recommend computing `x.min()` only once.

Comment: I don't get an error when I run this on Python 3.6.

Comment: @andrew_reece I do. I think the version matters as well. I'm on .22.

Comment: Seems like by `0.23.3` this problem has been fixed in Pandas.

Comment: @andrew_reece I'm also on Python 3.6.3. Pands 0.22. How does your output look like? Does it have 'NAME' column in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bug up until v0.22. From v0.23 onwards, non-numeric columns
>   are ignored by default.

Unfortunately, `groupby.apply` will attempt to run your lambda on *every* column, including the column you've grouped on ("NAME", which is a string).

You can confirm by checking the difference between

```
df.groupby('NAME')[['VAL1', 'VAL2']].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())

      VAL1  VAL2
NAME            
AAA      2   254
BBB     21   227
CCC     13    13
```

Versus

```
df.groupby('NAME')['NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError
```

Basically, explicit is better than implicit.

Alternatively, select all numeric columns and pass a Series as the grouper (note that this is slower than grouping on a column that belongs to the DataFrame), but this means you don't have to list out each column individually.

```
df.select_dtypes('number').groupby(df.NAME).apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())

      VAL1  VAL2
NAME            
AAA      2   254
BBB     21   227
CCC     13    13
```

Thanks to @JC.

Comment: Possibly a work around `df.select_dtypes('number').groupby(df.NAME).apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())`...

Comment: @JonClements `df.select_dtypes('number')`... that's neat, thanks!